# Variables in for loops

Tags: for-loop, var, python-3.9

Hello I am new to coding and have chosen to start off with the language python 3.x. I am running into a problem as when I declare a variable and insert it in a for loop the variable is not changed.

This can be seen as after running the code below the output remains as the original value of 5.

```
    i = 5

    for x in range(2):
     i + 1

    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `i = ...` to give it a value, then you do not use `i = ...` anywhere to give it a new value, so the value never changes. You need:

```
i = 5

for x in range(2):
 i = i + 1

print(i)
```

`i + 1` alone is not an error, but it does the calculation and throws the result away, as you did not say what else to do with it.